# converting from string to double

Tags: android

I m try to convert my string value to double, the values i take it from server with web service, here is my code:

```
private EditText lat;
private EditText lng;
```

i declare them as text

```
lat.setText(performance.latitude);
lng.setText(performance.longitude);
```

and now i declare them in my app screen as well,

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View k = inflater.inflate(R.layout.klient_fragment_kartela, container, false);

lng = (EditText) k.findViewById(R.id.longitude);
lat = (EditText) k.findViewById(R.id.latitude);

return k;
```

my problem is that i need to declare them as double in the method LatLng, but don't know how, can you help pls. Thnx all

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Double lat=Double.parseDouble(lat.getText().toString());
Double longi=Double.parseDouble(lng.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Double.parse()` should solve your problem:

```
Double lat1=Double.parse(yourString) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this like parsing the string into double :

`Double lat = Double.parseDouble(you string value);`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
Double.parseDouble(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way
                Double lat = Double.parseDouble("String");